# Call derived class function when saved in parent class type vector

Tags: c++

I have two classes A and B and a class AVector to store objects of class A and classes derived from class A.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    private:
        int id_;

    public:
        A(int id);
        int id() { return id_; }
};

A::A(int id) : id_{id} {}

class B : public A {
    private:

    public:
        B(int id);
        std::string sayHello() { return "Hello"; }
};

B::B(int id) : A(id) {}

class AVector : private std::vector<A> {
    private:

    public:
        void push_back(const A& inv);
        using std::vector<A>::size;
        using std::vector<A>::at;
        using std::vector<A>::begin;
        using std::vector<A>::end;
};

void AVector::push_back(const A& a) {
    std::vector<A>::push_back(a);
}

int main()
{
    A a1(3);
    A a2(8);
    B b1(12);
    std::cout << b1.sayHello() << std::endl; // Hello

    AVector av;
    av.push_back(a1);
    av.push_back(a2);
    av.push_back(b1);

//    std::cout << "id b1 = " << (av.at(2)).sayHello() << std::endl; // error
// main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
// main.cpp:54:43: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka class A}’ has no member named ‘sayHello’
//     std::cout << "id b1 = " << (av.at(2)).sayHello() << std::endl; // error
    A *a_ref = &(av.at(1));
    std::cout << "id a_ref(a1) = " << a_ref->id() << std::endl; // id a_ref(a1) = 8
//    B *b_ref = &(av.at(2)); // error
// main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
// main.cpp:60:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type* {aka A*}’ to ‘B*’ [-fpermissive]
//      B *b_ref = &(av.at(2)); // error
}
```

After putting an object of type B in the AVector, I can't cast it back to type B. Has all information about the derived class been lost after saving the object b1 in the AVector and can I somehow access the methods implemented in class B?

Answer (score 0):

The objects of the vector have type `A`. There is no `B` at all. So doing this:

```
av.at(2).sayHello()
```

doesn't make sense.

Perhaps you are coming from a language which uses virtual methods by default, like Java. This is not the case in C++.

In addition, even if you make the methods virtual, it is still not good enough, because the vector only stores `A` types. You would need to store pointers to `A` in order to enable polymorphism and avoid object slicing.